# MYSQL - limit amount of records that exceed count size

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have a query that counts the 'parent_id' value for each row and adds it within each row.

For example, if I have 4 records that have the has the value '1432' under 'parent_id' it will show the count value 4 under the 'count' column.

I am trying to limit the amount of rows based on the count number.

For example, let's say we want to exceed the number of records per 'parent_id' to 2. if the 'parent_id' has reached the third record, it just passes on and it won't return that record.

Example of existing table:

```
ID parent_id count(parent_id)
1  1234      2
2  1234      2
3  3221      3
4  3221      3
5  3221      3
6  5432      1
7  4312      1
```

The result I'd like to get is:

```
ID parent_id count(parent_id)
1  1234      2
2  1234      2
3  3221      2
4  3221      2
5  5432      1
6  4312      1
```

Comment: It would help if you added some sample data and expected output along with your query.

Comment: @jpw - I've added an example to the main thread. Thanks

Comment: What you present as an *existing* table is actually the result set of another query, isn't it so?

Comment: @Giorgos, you are correct. this is the result of my first query that includes the COUNT of the parent_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mihai's answer may work, but it is not guaranteed to work.  The problem is that MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in the `select`.  And, there are even occasions where it does not evaluate them in the expected order.

So, when using variables, it is safest to put all assignments in a single expression:

```
SELECT id, parent_id, rn
FROM (SELECT (@rn := if(@parent_id = parent_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@parent_id := parent_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn,
             t.*   
      FROM t CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0, @parent_id := '') params
      ORDER BY parent_id, id 
     ) t
WHERE rn <= 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a select per group query:

```
SELECT id, parent_id, rn
FROM (
    SELECT @rn:=CASE WHEN @parent_id=parent_id
                             THEN @rn+1                                
                             ELSE 1                          
                        END AS rn
         , @parent_id:=parent_id AS parent_id
        , id     
    FROM t, (SELECT @rn:=0,@parent_id:='') AS u

    ORDER BY parent_id,id 
) as s 
WHERE rn <= 2
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d02e/1)